# 25-32mm tube work in a 38mm tire?

Tags: road

Will a 700x 25-32 tube work in a 700x38 tire?

I just bought new tires that are 38mm but have a couple of new 25-32 tubes left from a different bike, can I get away with using these for light road use?

Paul

Comment: You may notice that your ride is a hair bumpy, due to the slightly narrower tire in the region of the valve.

Comment: A 23-28 tube did burst in my 35 mm tyres at the very spot @Daniel R Hicks mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. They may puncture or leak easier than correct size, but there is no immediate danger if you can't get the correct size or want to save a very small amount of money.